# Minor spacing bug on Area 51 in "Create New Discussion"

Tags: bug, design, area-51

There seems to be a very minor spacing bug on Area 51 on discussions, when creating a new discussion:

[image: Create new discussion link]

At first the user is presented with the empty text field, which has the proposal, and link, already in the text field, like so:

[image: Discussion field with pre-inserted proposal link]

and in text form

```
Proposal: [**XBee**][1]

  [1]:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96625/xbee
```

If the user then, adds a link (using the link button in the toolbar), then the second link has a space *after* the colon, whereas the first link did not, like so:

```
  [1]:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96625/xbee
  [2]: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807740.do
```

So the minor UI bug seems to be that the template for the pre-inserted proposal link is *missing* a space after the colon, a space that the **add link** button provides.